# What's the best way to detect Low memory?

Tags: android, android-library, android-memory

I'm building a library for android and I'm trying to avoid OutOfMemory errors by disabling some functionality when the memory is low

I have two solutions for that but I'm actually confused about which one is better

The first one is by using the `lowMemory` boolean in the `ActivityManager.MemoryInfo` This one gives an indication about the entire system memory overall

```
public static boolean isLowMemory(Context context) {
    if (context != null) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();

        if (activityManager != null) {
            activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
            return memoryInfo.lowMemory;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

the other way is by using `Runtime`

```
public static boolean isLowMemory() {
    final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    final long usedMemInMB = (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / 1048576L;
    final long maxHeapSizeInMB = runtime.maxMemory() / 1048576L;
    final long availHeapSizeInMB = maxHeapSizeInMB - usedMemInMB;
    return availHeapSizeInMB < 10;
}
```

I believe that this one should get the memory of the app itself, but my concern here is the Heap size will keep scaling if the Ram still has empty space that means maybe the heap can still scale up the allocated memory but I don't know if that's possible or not.

What do you think?

Comment: I think you're better off fixing whatever issue causes the OOM exceptions

Comment: There is also onTrimMemory in the Application class. But Tim is right. There are some good videos on Youtube for 'run -> profile'. Also, 'analyze -> inspect code' can reveal many common memory leaks.

Comment: My problem is that my android library usually runs in apps that are not mine. Few of them have bad memory usage which affects my library as well. I want to add a defensive code that allows me to stop intensive work when the memory is low.

Comment: As suggested by @TimCastelijns, you must profile your library. I think whatever your are asking is not suggestible.

Comment: @mnagy, how did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

you  can check activityManager.isLowRamDevice() function and also  memoryInfo.lowMemory . this will give you an indication